# Apex DOM get children at nth level

Tags: apex, xml, parser, dom

I have got the XML of the following format:

```
<parNode>
    <parNode2>
        <parNode3>
            <parNode4 name="name1">
                <flags attrVal="1" />
                <advancedData>
                    <advConfig>
                        <sync attrSync="true" />
                        <reqResp attrRespVal="1024418" />
                    </advConfig>
                    <metadata>
                    </metadata>
                </advancedData>
            </parNode4>
            <parNode4 name="name2">
                <flags attrVal="1" />
                <advancedData>
                    <advConfig>
                        <sync attrSync="false">
                        <reqResp attrRespVal="1024418" />
                    </advConfig>
                    <metadata>
                    </metadata>
                </advancedData>
            </parNode4>
        </parNode3>
        <sessessionId="" />
    </parNode2>
    <parNode2 respType="0">
        <parNode3>
            <resultSet result="2" />
        </parNode3>
        <responseError errCode="" />
    </parNode2>
</parNode>
```

> I need to parse till *parNode4* check name = *'name1'*.
>
> If *true*, then obtain the parameter *attrSync* under node *sync*.

Currently, I use `getChildren()` to check. But as the depth is 4 or more, code becomes cluttered and sometimes I get `time exceeded` error through the page. What I'd like to have is `Java's getElementsByTagName()` method equivalent here. However, Apex does not have this parsing functionality. How do I proceed about this? Will a ***dfs/recursive*** approach solve the time limit exceeded problem?

Comment: Why are you parsing XML in this way. From what context?

Comment: Do you have a suggestion apart from looping children?

Comment: You still need to provide more context